# Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6040000000d0 overflowed to 0x6040000000b8 (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++

class Solution {
public:
class Foo
{
public:
int x;
int y;
int depth;
bool visited;

```
        Foo(int x,int y,int depth){
            this->x=x;
            this->y=y;
            this->depth=depth;
            this->visited = false;
        }

    };
    class Compare
    {
    public:
        bool operator() (Foo a, Foo b)
        {
            return a.depth > b.depth;
        }
    };
//we put all the neighbours of the current location in a min heap and if all neighbours are bigger than the top of the heap then we pop the top and travel to its index and contyinue till we reach the end
    int swimInWater(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        int n = grid.size();
        int i=0,j=0, ans = 0;
        Foo l(i,j,grid[i][j]);
        priority_queue <Foo, vector<Foo>, Compare> g;
        g.push(l);
        Foo f = l;
        while(i!=n-1 && j!=n-1){
            Foo minn(0,0,INT_MAX);
            if(grid[i+1][j] > f.depth && i+1<n && j<n && i+1>=0 && j>=0){
              Foo down(i+1,j,grid[i+1][j]);
              minn = down;
              g.push(down);
            }
            if(grid[i-1][j] > f.depth && i-1<n && j<n && i-1>=0 && j>=0){
              Foo up(i-1,j,grid[i-1][j]);
              if(minn.depth>grid[i-1][j]){
                  minn = up;
              }
              g.push(up);
            }
            if(grid[i][j+1] > f.depth && i<n && j+1<n && i>=0 && j+1>=0){            
              Foo right(i,j+1,grid[i][j+1]);
              if(minn.depth>grid[i][j+1]){
                  minn = right;
              } 
              g.push(right);
            }
            if(grid[i][j-1] > f.depth && i<n && j-1<n && i>=0 && j-1>=0){                
              Foo left(i,j-1,grid[i][j-1]);
              if(minn.depth>grid[i][j-1]){
                  minn = left;
              }
              g.push(left);
            }
            if(g.top().depth <minn.depth){
                f = g.top();
                i = f.x;
                j = f.y;
                ans = f.depth;
                g.pop();
            }else{
                f = minn;
                i = f.x;
                j = f.y;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Question - https://leetcode.com/problems/swim-in-rising-water/
this is showing the following error

```
Error - Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6040000000d0 overflowed to 0x6040000000b8 (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34
```

Comment: where is `grid` populated? Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: `grid[i-1][j]` is out of bounds when `i == 0` you need to check if `i > 1` (or `i-1 >= 0`) before you access `grid[i-1]` not after